# Why does Internet Explorer show this site centered versus Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: asp.net, html, cross-browser

I have built a website and when my users load up

**http://info.salemgolfclub.org/Account/Logon**

the username and password user entry controls show left justified in the panel in Firefox and Chrome  **but Internet Explorer shows them centered in the panel**.

I want Internet Explorer to show left justified as well.  How do I determine what Firefox and Chrome seem to figure out but Internet Explorer struggles with so every browser is consistent?

I would appreciate comments both on this particular example as well as general comments on best practices to avoid this type of situation in the future.

Comment: IE 6? Cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can reproduce this with IE 8.  Safari left justifies.  Have you underspecified the appearance in ../Content/site.css?

Comment: A best practice (which I systematically neglect) is to test your CSS on IE6 since the beginning, and not procrastinating this horrible but nonetheless necessary task!

Comment: I purposely *do not* front-load CSS compatibility with regards to IE6.  The longer that people keep doing so, the longer that IE6 will live.

Comment: It might be useful to use a reset stylesheet in your project to standardize the defaults of elements across browsers. Some good reset stylesheets are Eric Meyer's - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and Yahoo's - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set text-align to left.

```
<fieldset style="text-align:left;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe IE's default style centers a label.
Just set `text-align: left` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

...start with setting text-align: left 
... you might have to float:left some elements